# Get Facebook cookies while login using CURL PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl, cookies

I want to get Facebook cookies then save it into text file. I can login successfully But i cant save cookies info my directory as `txt` format.

```
 $cookie = 'cookie.txt'
 function Get_Login($em,$pa,$cookie){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($em).'&pass='.urlencode($pa).'&login=Login');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$ip);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);              
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9900; en) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.0.346 Mobile Safari/534.11+');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,"https://www.facebook.com");

  $body = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error
  ($ch));
  }
```

Using this code i can login successfully. I want to save cookies file into my directory.

Comment: You are not supposed to login to Facebook using any such automatisms. If you want to interact with Facebook - use their API.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

      $body = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
      $cookie = 'cookie.txt';
      // Open the file to get existing content
      $current = file_get_contents($cookie);
      // Append a new person to the file
      $current .= $body;
      // Write the contents back to the file
      file_put_contents($cookie, $current);
  ?>
```

Comment: I try this  $current = file_get_contents($cookie); show error no file or directory found

Comment: First you must create a file in the directory : `<?php
$file = 'cookie.txt';
$handle = fopen($file , 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file ); //implicitly creates file

?>`